# Problems with graphics while booting UBUNTU

Tags: boot, kernel, screen, intel

1. I have installed the minimal UBUNTU 15.04 - **NO GUI and I DO NOT want it**.
2. This Ubuntu has **3.19.0-49-generic** kernel.
3. When the system boots with this kernel at the beginning I can see strange characters/letters/numbers - totally unreadable (see attachement). But after few seconds my screen is going black and nice, white, readable characters are displayed - so it works. Nevermind wrong beginning (see attachement).
4. After login I ran this command for you, to help me to discover something:

   **sudo lspci | grep VGA**

   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)

   **sudo lshw -C display**

   ```
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: Intel Corporation
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 2
      bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
      version: 21
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
      resources: irq:119 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
   ```

BUT

5. I wanted a realtime kernel so I builded one - **3.18.25-rt23**
6. I successfuly builded a new realtime kernel BUT my graphics goes wrong. While booting I can see unreadable characters/letters and later is my screen totally black. Linux is running because I can access to it thru serial console. Serial console is OK.

I do not want HD picture, I do not want the X server or similar. I want simple, stupid black window with white characters and VGA monitor and I cannot have it. I tried many options without success.

This is my actual /etc/default/grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU for any help. On another PC I do not have strange characters/letters. But I need it on my Gigabyte N3050N-D2P board!

UPDATE:
I think that this is only kernel problem. I tried to recompile kernel again with some settings in Graphics menu and it is better - I still have a black screen after booting but when it boots the display is flashing and I can see for a moment boot messages clearly. But monitor is flashing and then goes black again.

I attached a pictures from my booting screen:

Start of booting:
[image]

After few seconds with generic 3.19.0 kernel
[image]
[image]

Booting with 3.18.25 kernel: (Start like this):
[image]

And then just 2x flash with readable boot messages **and then it is going black forever**.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys... I build a 4.4.1 RT kernel and finally **I have a nice, readable boot messages and console screen! BUT (why there is always BUT):**

Graphics for example on alsamixer is really bad, could you tell me why?

**uname -a**

```
Linux ubuntu 4.4.1-rt6 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Feb 24 04:27:02 CET 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

**sudo lshw -C display**

```
  description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 21
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:115 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

**sudo lspci  |grep VGA**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
```

**sudo fbset -i**

```
mode "1280x1024"
    geometry 1280 1024 1280 1024 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    accel true
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : inteldrmfb
    Address     : 0x900c0000
    Size        : 5242880
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 1
    YPanStep    : 1
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 5120
    Accelerator : No
```

**cat /etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

ALSAMIXER looks like this:

[image]